# Fix flex element in the end of first row

Tags: html, css

I need to fix some elements always at the end of the first row on flex container (with `flex-wrap: wrap`).
Examples (pay attention on button "Expand" ):

[image: 1]

I tried to use 'row-reverse' + 'order: -1', but in this case, elements moved to the new row from left to right (when I need from right to left).

[image: 2]

Here is my snippet: https://jsbin.com/divavosafu/1/edit?html,css,output

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: However, this is not possible with flexbox as outlined.

Comment: Why don't you set up columns for these elements e.g. (| Numbers | | Expand | | Right Buttons |)

Comment: @HaldenCollier, when numbers moved to the second row it should have the same width as whole parent container. In your suggestion container Numbers will have width = Parent container - Expand - Right Buttons.
See illustration in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217438/fix-flex-element-in-the-end-of-first-row#comment102811440_58217641

Answer (score 0):

Just nest the numbered buttons in an element and make both it and the main container a flex container:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
}

.numbers {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.expand {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="numbers">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="expand">
    <div class="item">Expand</div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="item right1">Right 1</div>
    <div class="item right2">Right 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Second row should have the same width as parent. It's required. [illustration](https://i.snipboard.io/9lbAJk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found something similar to solution, but button "Expand" should be in the left "container"

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.item {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #CECECE;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="right">
      <div class="item expand">Expand</div>
      <div class="item ">Right 1</div>
      <div class="item ">Right 2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
  </div>
```